# How to determine bufferedimage color type in java

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I need a way to determine the type of this `BufferedImage` in java  `(Binary, Gray, 24 bit color, 8 bit color)` ?

It is something like `BufferedImage.getType()` method ,that returns an integer that determines that ,but I need a way to handle that. And if there is an Algorithm that detects it like the color is  grey if red=green=blue and so on. I will be thankful if you tell me about it

All regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either, as you suggest, use `BufferedImage.getType()` (you can find what the `int` return values mean, in the [API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#field_summary)).

Or, use `BufferedImage.getColorModel()` to get more information, like `ColorSpace` (`ColorModel.getColorSpace()`) to determine color space type, like RGB, CMYK or Gray, or special color spaces, like sRGB, AdobeRGB, PhotoYCC, IEXYZ, Lab etc.

If you need to figure out if your image in 24/32 bit depth with RGB color model really is all gray, you are out of luck, and instead have to loop though all the pixel values and see if R == G == B (perhaps with a small threshold).